# importScripts returns undefined in the web workers

Tags: javascript, promise, web-worker

For earlier browser versions, Promise is undefined in web workers. So I am using a [polyfill Promise](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) by importScripts('Promise.js'), if Promise is undefined. But still I get an undefined object in return.

```
var promise;
if(typeof Promise === undefined) {
  self.importScripts('./Promise.js').Promise;
}

promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  var url = ajaxArgs.url || '',
      data = ajaxArgs.data || {},
      type = ajaxArgs.method || 'GET',
      isGet = type === 'GET',
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ........
}
```

How can I make this work for web workers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`importScripts` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) doesn't return anything. When  you access a `.Promise` property on the call, this will throw, and your code stops executing. Btw, `typeof` never returns `undefined`, so you were lucky and it was never exected.

```
if (typeof Promise !== "function") self.importScripts('./Promise.js');

var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    …
});
```